# value returned from a function is not same as received. Why?

Tags: c

I am returning values 1 or 0 from function isprime(0 when it is not prime and 1 when it is prime) but when i print the returned value of x(return value of isprime) it is not same as what I returned from isprime. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isprime(int b);

main()
{
    int a,rem,i;

    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i = 1; i < a; i++)
    {

        rem = a % i;
        if(rem == 0)
        {
            int x = isprime(i);
            printf(" value of x returned for i = %d is  %d", i, x);
            if(x = 1)
            {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
        return (0);
}

/**
 *
 *returns 1 if b is prime else returns 0
 */

int isprime(int b)
{
    int x, count = 0;
    printf("input recieved %d \n", b);
    for(x = 1; x <= b;  x++)
    {
        if (b % x == 0)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        printf("the value of count is %d\n", count);
    }
    if(count == 2) {
        printf("returning the value as 1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("returning the value as 0\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(x = 1)
```

`=` is assignment. You need `==` operator instead. You are doing correct in other `if` conditions though.

Also, the logic of calculating prime numbers is inefficient. You can break the loop once the count is greater than 2.

```
if (b % x == 0)
{
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 2)
    {
       // This ensures you are returning correct value later.
       break;
    }
}
```

Have a look at this algorithm: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct.

For removing such kind of mistakes use it like

```
if(1=x)
```

using this approach you can avoid such behavior.

Here I am just approaching to avoid typo mistakes.

Comment: Turning your compiler warnings on is better than writing your program logic backwards, in my view. In any case, Yoda conditions only work when one of the operands is a constant, which isn't always true.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths...Here I am just approaching to avoid typo mistakes.

Comment: Yes, and I think using compiler warnings is better, because: 1. they always work, Yoda conditions don't always work; and 2. You don't have to mentally reverse the logic when you read your code.